# Creating rqt plugin

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

this is my package: https://github.com/azhar92/GUI-for-AV.git

When I open rqt and try to open the plugin from the drop-down menu using the following steps

```
cd ~/catkin_ws
catkin_make
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
rqt --force-discover
```

I can see the name of my package when in the rqt gui, but when i click it,

I get the following error in the terminal output:

```
[ERROR] [1482121854.496133919]: Failed to load nodelet [rqt_test1/MyPlugin_1] of type [rqt_test1/MyPlugin]: MultiLibraryClassLoader: Could not create object of class type rqt_test1::MyPlugin as no factory exists for it. Make sure that the library exists and was explicitly loaded through MultiLibraryClassLoader::loadLibrary()
RosPluginlibPluginProvider::load_explicit_type(rqt_test1/MyPlugin) failed creating instance
PluginManager._load_plugin() could not load plugin "rqt_test1/MyPlugin": RosPluginlibPluginProvider.load() could not load plugin "rqt_test1/MyPlugin"
```

i think it has to do with the registration of the plugin. any form of guidance will be helpful. Thank you.

Plugin.xml  : https://github.com/azhar92/GUI-for-AV/blob/master/plugin.xml

Code:

```
<library path="lib/librqt_test1">

 <class name="rqt_test1/MyPlugin" type="rqt_test1::MyPlugin" base_class_type="rqt_gui_cpp::Plugin">

   <description>

4 buttons to switch between 4 different modes.

</description>

 <qtgui>

  <group>

   <label>Visualization</label>

    <statustip>Plugins related to visualization.</statustip>

  </group>

 <label>test1</label>

 <statustip>4 buttons to switch between 4 different modes.</statustip>

 </qtgui>

</class>

</library>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250299/creating-rqt-plugin/) by [Azhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/27936/azhar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2016-12-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-19**:\

> i think it has to do with the registration of the plugin

If you feel that is the case, then please include at least a snippet of code where you show how you implemented that bit.

This question will become worthless otherwise if/when your repository is removed/deleted/changed.

**Comment by [Azhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/27936/azhar/) on 2016-12-19**:
I have edit the question. let me know if there are any other things you need. Thank you!

i have not changed my repository!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-19**:
So where is the code where you actually *register* your plugin (or really: export it / make it known to class loader)? Please include that in your question.

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2016-12-19**:
From a quick glance, I don't see anything to cause that error. But you can delete this from CMakeLists:

```
install(PROGRAMS scripts/${PROJECT_NAME}/gauge_script.py
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)
```

**Comment by [Azhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/27936/azhar/) on 2016-12-20**:
@AndyZelenak, i tried it but it doesn't help. same error ;(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Compare your main.cpp to [my_plugin.cpp](https://github.com/UTNuclearRoboticsPublic/gauges/blob/master/src/rqt_gauges/my_plugin.cpp). You don't have this line at the bottom:

```
PLUGINLIB_DECLARE_CLASS(rqt_gauges, MyPlugin, rqt_gauges::MyPlugin, rqt_gui_cpp::Plugin)
```

And you're missing this function (which seems important):

```
void MyPlugin::initPlugin(qt_gui_cpp::PluginContext& context)
```

So go back and spend some time fixing those obvious issues. I think we would be more motivated to help if you upvoted good answers, too.

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2016-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1